# Is it possible to delay the reveal of information without further information?

Tags: encryption, delay

Scenario:

> I send encrypted information to a client program.
>
> I want to the information to display 1 year later.
>
> No further information will be sent by me.

If the user of the client program can do analysis of the binary file of the program, is it possible to prevent the early reveal of the information?

Comment: Of course it isn't. The client program has to know how to decrypt that information, so all they need is already on their computer. All you can do it make it harder for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, such a thing is not possible. If the program is able to decrypt the data without further interaction, it **must** possess the key.

Therefore, even with signed timestamping, you cannot prevent someone from reverse-engineering your program, taking the key, and doing the decryption.

EDIT: Though you could at least in theory implement something like this indirectly, by requiring a computionally intensive puzzle to be solved for retrieving the key (which takes a year on the average!), but this is unreliable at best (faster/slower hardware) and will certainly not find acceptance among your users/customers. Be prepared to receive hate mails if you do that :-)

Comment: ha, I like the puzzle idea because it treats users like the swine they are!

Comment: All in all, using puzzles to guarantee a certain time threshold is an ingenious idea. To my knowledge, the hashcash project was the first one that came up with such an idea to ensure that you spend a certain minimum amount of time (or cpu power) sending an email, which effectively limits the amount of spam one can send out (in the meantime Sun had the idea patented slightly reworded as "method and apparatus to protect against DoS attacks"). The problem with the OP is that if you block a user's computer for an entire year crunching numbers, you'll probably be hung, drawn, and quartered.

Comment: I believe the notion of "client puzzles" was developed at least no later than the dawn of deployment of SSL and other public key crypto in '90s to combat simple denial of service attacks. But to my knowledge nobody ever implemented them.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I think it is not possible as you described, unless server store a part of the secret and deliver it to the client at the right moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you've sent the client all the info they need to do the decryption, there is no way to force them to wait a year before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a timemachine and base your key on a hash of, say, the Dow Jones index one year from now as well as some other data that can't be pre-calculated. So unless you have some inside info that only you know about the day the decryption should occur, I think you're facing a quite impossible task

Comment: Tell me how you would obtain the encryption key now for the Dow Jones index one year from now?